# Website template with backend coding

Tags: web-apps

I am looking for a template that actually has backend coding ready with the source codes.

Code can be in PHP, ASP.NET in VB.NET or C#.
DB could be done in MS SQL, MySQL, JSON or any other means as long as it works.

The site backend should contain member management, vendor company/person management and each vendor could be searched by location and qualification.

The front end that should work with portable device browsers (iOS and Android). Preferably Bootstrap would be great but not mandatory. 
Also if possible to have localization ready.

I know I am asking for a lot, and we might have to develope most of it. But we are ready to pay for the template software which we can alter to save ourselves some time.

Here is an example site that actually does similar process specified for lawyers: http://www.avvo.com/find-a-lawyer

Any suggestions would be great to get us started.

Comment: Not sure I understand … do you look for a [tag:cms]?

Comment: Cms would work but It has to have a module that already has member/vendor requirements written in the question.

Comment: Compare CMS and select feature using a wizard at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/

Comment: I went through a few cms solutions but cannot figure out if any have vendor/person listing solution, there is a ton out there, does anyone know if any actually have this functionality?